# Facing problem including reactstrap in my web project

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I am trying to install reactstrap in my react project using commands like "npm i reactstrap react react-dom" or "npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom" but getting error everytime.
I tried to search Stack Overflow but have not found a solution.

Please help.

I am getting the following error:

```
"npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.2" from @restart/context@2.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@restart/context
npm ERR!     @restart/context@"^2.1.4" from react-bootstrap@1.4.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-bootstrap
npm ERR!       react-bootstrap@"^1.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (prop-types-extra, react-bootstrap, react-dom, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"0.14.x || ^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-popper@1.3.7
npm ERR! node_modules/reactstrap/node_modules/react-popper
npm ERR!   react-popper@"^1.3.6" from reactstrap@8.8.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/reactstrap
npm ERR!     reactstrap@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/shashikant/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shashikant/.npm/_logs/2021-01-02T08_50_48_353Z-debug.log
(base) MacBook-Pro:confusion shashikant$ sudo npm install i reactstrip react react-dom
Password:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/reactstrip - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'reactstrip@*' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/shashikant/.npm/_logs/2021-01-02T08_56_31_508Z-debug.log"
```

Comment: Try installing them separately as the error says that reactstrap does not support react-17 yet

Comment: If you failed to do so just install react@16.x.x

Answer (score 0):

I used "npm install --save-dev reactstrap react react-dom --force" and it solved my problem.

Comment: use --legacy-peer-deps and reactstrap will get installed without an issue